# строки внутри рамки из символа ( в данном случае ' + ' )

Tags: javascript

Как сделать?

```
++++++++++
+ Create +
+      a +
+ frame  +
++++++++++
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для спортивного интереса

```js
function frame(words, c){
   var len = Math.max(...words.map(x => x.length));
   
   var l = console.log;
   
   l(c.repeat(len + 4));
   words.forEach( s =>  l( c + s.padStart(len + 1) + ' ' + c));   
   l(c.repeat(len + 4));
}

frame(['Create', 'a', 'frame'], '+');
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно что-то вроде такого сделать

```js
frame(['Create', 'a', 'frame'], '+');


function frame(array, border) {
  var line = "";
  var maxLength = 0;
  var baseBorder = "";

  // Находим длину наибольшей строки.
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    maxLength = maxLength < item.length ? item.length : maxLength;
  });

  // Формируем верхнюю и нижнюю границу.
  for (var i = 0; i < maxLength + 4; i++) {
    baseBorder += border;
  }

  // Формируем и выводим строки.
  console.log(baseBorder);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    line = "" + border + " ";

    // Прижимаем строки к правой стороне.
    for (var j = 0; j < (maxLength - array[i].length); j++) {
      line += " ";
    }
    line += array[i] + " " + border;
    console.log(line);
  }
  console.log(baseBorder);
}
```